# Could not match expected type with actual type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've written the following code:

```
type Mass = Double
type Position = (Double, Double)
type Velocity = (Double, Double)

data Body = Body Mass Position Velocity
data System = System [Body]

renderBody :: Body -> Picture
renderBody (Body mass (x, y) velocity) = object
  where 
    object = translated x y (solidCircle mass)

renderSystem :: System -> Picture
renderSystem (System []) = blank
renderSystem (System (x:xs)) = renderBody(x)<>renderSystem(System(xs))

moveBody :: Double -> Body -> Body
moveBody time (Body mass (x, y) (vx, vy)) = new_body
  where
    new_x = x + vx * time
    new_y = y + vy * time
    new_body = (Body mass (new_x, new_y) (vx, vy))

updateSystem :: Double -> System -> System
updateSystem time (System []) = (System [])
updateSystem time (System(x:xs)) = moveBody time x : updateSystem time System(xs)
```

I could not understand the following [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNSR8.png)

What's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `updateSysten time (System(x:xs)) = moveBody time x : updateSystem time (System xs)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't applying `updateSystem time` to a value of type `System`; you are applying it to the data constructor `System` and a list of `Body` values `xs`. You need to adjust your parentheses to create the necessary value of type `System`.

```
updateSystem time (System(x:xs)) = moveBody time x : updateSystem time (System xs)
```

However, you can simplify the definition of `updateSystem` by using `map` on the list that `System` wraps.

```
updateSystem :: Double -> System -> System
updateSystem time (System xs) = System (map (moveBody time) xs)
```

Extract the value of type `[Body]`, map `moveBody time` over it to get a new list of `Body`'s, and rewrap the list as a new `System` value.

Comment: Thank you, you help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom prepending operator for your type, e.g. `.:` to wrap list prepending for `System`:

```
type Mass = Double                                                             
type Position = (Double, Double)                                               
type Velocity = (Double, Double)                                               
                                                                               
data Body = Body Mass Position Velocity                                        
data System = System [Body]                                                    
                                                                               
moveBody :: Double -> Body -> Body                                             
moveBody time (Body mass (x, y) (vx, vy)) = new_body                           
  where                                                                        
    new_x = x + vx * time                                                      
    new_y = y + vy * time                                                      
    new_body = (Body mass (new_x, new_y) (vx, vy))                             
                                                                               
(.:) :: Body -> System -> System                                               
(.:) b (System x) = System (b : x)                                             
                                                                               
updateSystem :: Double -> System -> System                                     
updateSystem time (System []) = (System [])                                    
updateSystem time (System(x:xs)) = moveBody time x .: updateSystem time (System xs)
```

You get an error because `System` is not a list, so you can not prepend elemens to it just by using `:` operator.

You also had a bad notation of `System(xs)` instead of `(System xs)`, you should to construct `System` from list at first, and pass it to functions after this.